# Update single field for rows grouped by name

Tags: sql-server

[image: Sample Output]

I need to update a SSN field with the same number for each person. Doesn't matter which SSN it is since they are invalid, just need them for unique identifiers in SSN format. This means either min or max number would be acceptable. Current table includes rows which could be grouped by multiple columns to ensure that each person is unique, such as first name, last name, address and patient number.

How would I take one of John Doe's EmpID1 values and copy it to every one of his rows, then do the same for Jane Doe's multiple rows?

Thanks!

Comment: Join the set of Jane's records to the set of johns single record. Update Janes.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only needs to be in a "SSN Format" then we can use `row_number`. Also your question was contradicting since you stated you needed *unique identifiers in SSN format* but also stated *need to update a SSN field with the same number for each person* which would mean the same SSN for everyone. The solution below was based off the expected output you provided. This is easier than swapping records.

```
create table #testTable (EmpID1 varchar(11) null, LastName2 char(3), FirstName3 char(4))
insert into #testTable
values
(null,'DOE','JOHN'),
(null,'DOE','JOHN'),
(null,'DOE','JOHN'),
(null,'DOE','JOHN'),
(null,'DOE','JOHN'),
(null,'DOE','JOHN')


;with cte as
(select 
    RN = row_number() over (order by (select null)) + 111111111
    , * 
 from #testTable)

update cte
set EmpID1 = stuff(stuff(RN,4,0,'-'),7,0,'-')

select * from #testTable

drop table #testTable
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
|   EmpID1    | LastName2 | FirstName3 |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| 111-11-1112 | DOE       | JOHN       |
| 111-11-1113 | DOE       | JOHN       |
| 111-11-1114 | DOE       | JOHN       |
| 111-11-1115 | DOE       | JOHN       |
| 111-11-1116 | DOE       | JOHN       |
| 111-11-1117 | DOE       | JOHN       |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: The EmpID1 field has been assigned through previous joins and needs to stay the same. John Doe was populated with fake SSNs because he didn't match against an existing database. This means any of the SSNs already assigned to him can be used to populate all of his rows. For example, can take his first SSN 970-42-3783 and fill it down for the rest of his records. Then do the same for Jane Doe - grab the existing EmpID1 and copy it down for each of her rows. I don't actually need to generate new, fake SSNs - need to use what is already populated. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query statement.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeTable TABLE(EmpID1 VARCHAR(20),FirstName VARCHAR(100),LastName VARCHAR(100),PatientNumber INT)
INSERT INTO @EmployeeTable
SELECT '970-42-3783','John','Doe',1 UNION ALL SELECT '971-42-3780','John','Doe',1 UNION ALL SELECT '973-42-4081','John','Doe',1

SELECT * FROM @EmployeeTable

DECLARE @FirstName AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LastName AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @PatientNumber INT
DECLARE @EmpID1 AS VARCHAR(20)

DECLARE EmployeeCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT A.FirstName,A.LastName,A.PatientNumber FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfRow,FirstName,LastName,PatientNumber FROM @EmployeeTable
    GROUP BY FirstName,LastName,PatientNumber) A
OPEN EmployeeCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM EmployeeCursor into @FirstName,@LastName,@PatientNumber

    WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @EmpID1 = (SELECT TOP 1 EmpID1 FROM  @EmployeeTable WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName AND PatientNumber = @PatientNumber)

        UPDATE @EmployeeTable SET EmpID1 = @EmpID1
        WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName AND PatientNumber = @PatientNumber

        FETCH NEXT FROM EmployeeCursor into @FirstName,@LastName,@PatientNumber
    END

    CLOSE EmployeeCursor
    DEALLOCATE EmployeeCursor

    SELECT * FROM @EmployeeTable
```

Previous Data

```
EmpID1          FirstName   LastName    PatientNumber
970-42-3783     John        Doe             1
971-42-3780     John        Doe             1
973-42-4081     John        Doe             1
```

After Updated

```
EmpID1          FirstName   LastName    PatientNumber
970-42-3783     John        Doe             1
970-42-3783     John        Doe             1
970-42-3783     John        Doe             1
```

Comment: @John Barnes, If you have any further confusion, please let me know. Thanks.